# Why does typescript not recognise that the keys of a generic are of type string?

Tags: typescript, generics, record

Here's a contrived example to demonstrate the issue

```js
function funcWithGeneric<T extends Record<string, any>>(propertyName: keyof T){
    propertyName.toUpperCase() 
    // ^ Errors with
    // Property 'toUpperCase' does not exist on type 'string | number | symbol'.
    // Property 'toUpperCase' does not exist on type 'number'.(2339)
}
```

I assumed that the `Record<string` part would be enough to tell Typescript that the propertyName will be of a string type but apparently not.

Why is this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While `T` does have to extend `Record<string,any>` it isn't limited to properties having only string as keys.

consider:

```js
const test: Record<string, any> = {
  a:"test",
  [3]:"test"
}
```

this is a valid assignment, while `keyof test` essentially is `string|number`

Is there a reason why you have T as a generic while you don't use in the function definition?

what you can do is something like

```js
function funcWithGeneric<T extends Record<K, any>, K extends string>(propertyName: K){
    propertyName.toUpperCase() 
}

funcWithGeneric("test")

funcWithGeneric(4)
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAYw9gdgzgLgBDAprAXHASo8AnAJgHlmwEsIBzAGjgEMIBPAPjgF44BvYOGlAIiVh4VOcANoBmALq9+MHsAC+wYADMArhBAxikOGo0B1YjAAWAcUQREJEPgAqcRAA8kEXFAxYwefAGkqtRiofB2cLNzgiUjIGAAoAB2wwOKsYOgA5agBbRDQfAEoOLi4EpJT0rMQAOhgwAFU45OwAYWooRBi8uAUlPRBDE3NLaxi+ZFk8nvU+ozMLK2IQGIAWPKA)

Comment: Ah that makes sense, thanks for the clearing that up.